# Can a function doing nothing change an object?

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

Why does a function doing nothing change an object?

I have the following code:

```
void sample(SList a)
{
    cout << "\nIn Function";
    a.print();
}

int main()
{
    srand(500);
    int total = 10;
    SList llist;

    for(int i = 0; i < total; i++)
    {
        llist.add_head(rand() % 100);
    }

    llist.print();
    llist.print();

    sample(llist);
    llist.print();
    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
70  69  14  3   18  71  70  17  57  98  
70  69  14  3   18  71  70  17  57  98  
In Function
70  69  14  3   18  71  70  17  57  98  
0   34365728    34365696    34365664    34365632    34365600    34365568    34365536    34365504    34365472
```

My question is that a function `sample` which has nothing related to SList, is changing the SList. How is it doing that? SList is a singly linked list.

I think it is something to do with pass-by-value. It would be great if someone shows me the point I am ignorantly missing.

**EDIT:** The answer to the title question would be yes. Please look at the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Look at `SList's` copy constructor and destructor. My guess without seeing them is that the copy constructor makes a shallow copy of the data and the destructor deletes that data. The problem is that the copy constructor is called when `sample` is called and then the destructor is called when `sample` exits. There are several ways to fix this.

You can pass the `SList` by reference. This will prevent the copy constructor and destructor from being called.

You can deep copy the data in the copy constructor.

Another solution is to have `SList` store its data as a `shared_ptr` rather than raw data.